# Unix Shell Script: Remove duplicates from line ignore blank lines

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sh

How can I "remove" the duplicate lines from a txt file while ignoring blank lines? Rather than removing I want to add a prefix of `//` (comment) to the line.

I have found from a search that this command `awk ' !x[$0]++'` will remove all duplicate lines from a file as well as blank lines. Modification to that `awk` command if possible would be great.

Original Input:

```
foo
bar
cat

dog
turtle
cat
bar
lion
bear

bird
fish
cat
```

Output:

```
foo
bar
cat

dog
turtle
// cat
// bar
lion
bear

bird
// lion
bird
```

Just need to ignore blank newlines and

Comment: Add some sample input data and your desired output.

Comment: Your output is not in sync with input especially for last three lines. I have added a solution, hopefully that is something what you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one way using `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NF{x[$0]++; print (x[$0]>1?"//"$0:$0); next}1' file
foo
bar
cat

dog
turtle
//cat
//bar
lion
bear

bird
fish
//cat
```

`NF` tells awk to perform action only on non-blank lines. We increment the array `x` storing each line as key. We print the line with `//` prefix if the count is greater than 1 else we just print the line as is. `1` allows us to retain the blank lines.

Comment: Nice! The explanation could be a little better. `NF` is equivalent to `NF>0`, so if there's at least one field, then the code in braces is executed, which includes `next` so that no further code is executed. If the number of fields is `0`, then the second block of code is executed, which is a non-zero value (any non-zero value will do), which is interpreted as true and the default print action is performed.

Comment: @jaypal Apologies.  It wasn't exactly the same.  That one wanted to delete, this one comment.  That said, your awk answers are always enlightening.

Comment: You can shorten it a bit, eg: `NF && x[$0]++ { $0 = "//" $0 } 1`.